# Logstash with tcp input plugin not forwarding logs

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash

I have the four containers (Elastic search (8.10.2), Logstash, Kibana, and my application container)  running on my local machine and the application is configured to forward logs to Logstash. I was previously using UDP to forward the logs on port 9600 and wanting to change to TCP, but facing some issues in doing so.

Here's my `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 9600
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
    index => "titan-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
    ilm_enabled => "true"
    ilm_rollover_alias => "myapp"
    ilm_pattern => "{now/d}-000001"
    ilm_policy => "myapp-policy"
    user => "elastic"
    password => <elastic-password>
  }
}
```

Logstash service:

```
  Logstash:
    image: logstash:8.10.2
    container_name: logstash
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./logstash/:/logstash_dir
    command: logstash -f /logstash_dir/logstash.conf 
    depends_on:
      - Elasticsearch
    ports:
    - '9600:9600'
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
```

docker-compose of the application:

```
logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://localhost:9600"
```

With the above configuration I'm able to see the index but not getting any data.
Also, the Logstash container throws the following error

```
warning: thread "[main]<tcp" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
    translate at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/3.1.0/gems/i18n-1.14.1/lib/i18n.rb:210
  inputworker at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:427
  start_input at /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:405
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [fix](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/15407) for this issue has been merged in github. Also [this](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/15451). If you are running 8.10.x you can downgrade to 8.9.x or upgrade to 8.11.x.

It is related to the JRuby update in 8.10. The i18n code has [extensive comments](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/7cf09474b77fd41e65d979134b0525f67cf371b0/lib/i18n.rb#L197) about how calls to the .t alias will fail in different versions of ruby. The call is [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/6046402a3582eb813cfdc9c3ed5dca89e961ed6e/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb#L427).